# Does masstransit support empty body RMQ messages?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to consume a message with empty body using Masstransit as I am interested only in it's headers, but when I am sending the message with empty body, it is routed directly to _error queue and there it has the following error:

> MT-Fault-Message:  The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
>
> MT-Fault-StackTrace:   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes) at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read() at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)

Does Masstransit support empty bodied messages?

Comment: Based on the exception, I'd say no, it doesn't. You'd need to copy the built-in deserializer and modify it to handle an empty body.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it does not support any format which it can not deserialize as per [the discussion on MT](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/4971).

[Messages need to be serialized](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/serialization).

> MassTransit uses types for messages. Serializers are used convert those types into their respective format (such as JSON, XML, BSON, etc.), which is sent to the message broker. A corresponding deserializer is then used to convert the serialized format back into a type.